# python3 pip install cannot find packages

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I been installing pytorch and some associated packages on a number of machines. One package needed is 'torchvision', which is available in version 0.13.0 according to the search on pypi.org/search .

I installed a fresh python3.11 with pip on windows, did a pip install --upgrade pip , then tried to install 'torchvision'.

The errormessage is:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torchvision (    from versions: 0.1.6, 0.1.7, 0.1.8, 0.1.9, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.2.post2,     0.2.2.post3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torchvisionERROR: Could not find a     version that satisfies the requirement torchvision (from versions: 0.1.6, 0    .1.7, 0.1.8, 0.1.9, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.2.post2, 0.2.2.post3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torchvision
```

clearly, the errormessage shows only some very outdated versions of the package.

pip search torchvision   does not help, as it just hints to search on the pypi website instead. Searching there finds the 0.13.0 version.

I lack the understanding of how pip selects a version and where it stores or gets the package index. Is it possible that I have a bad package index? (the Python3.11 is fresh installed)

Therer have been hints here on stackoverflow on how to install using the full path to the package, but on some other machines pip just finds 'torchvision' in a usable version.

How do I update/install it using pip's own package index?

(I have another windows machine where the pip install just worked. No idea what is the difference)

Comment: Do you also have `python2` installed on your machine? Could be that you need to use `pip3`.

Comment: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/ -- Use `path/to/python3.11 -m pip install torchvision`, well actually you should create a Python virtual environment first.

Comment: I actually only did python3 -m pip ...   , so pip3 is not the issue. And I want to put the stuff in the default environment - without venv. My question aims at how can I debug the package repo it looks at? Is there an index somewhere?